# SMTP details on .ini

Tags: javascript, php, smtp, ini

We have a printer embedded with a print solutions software, which has a scan2email function. When attempting to scan, the job goes to a local server which retrieves the SMTP details from a .ini file.

`Initial Java Heap Size (in MB) wrapper.java.initmemory=384 ;
Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB) wrapper.java.maxmemory=512 ;
SMTP settings smtpServer=smtp.office365.com smtpServerBackup= emailSender=test@test.co.za smtpUser=test@test.co.za smtpPassword=test12345!!!`

The issue, scan2email doesnt work with error "smtp 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful" from the logs. When investigated by checking Firewall Traffic, we notice that the local server sends out comms to O365 SMTP BUT using IMAP Port 993 and not SMTP 587 or 465.

Is there anywhere on this .ini file whereby we can specify this port? Or even better, what is the issue if not the port? Searched high & low with no solution.

Ps. Tested the O365 account by logging into it. No authentication issue.

Comment: Ok, turns our I cannot post an image due to less rep points... But here is the sampel code :

Comment: ; Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=384

; Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=512

; SMTP settings
smtpServer=smtp.office365.com
smtpServerBackup=
emailSender=test@test.co.za
smtpUser=test@test.co.za
smtpPassword=test12345!!!

Comment: I hope those are not the *actual* smtp server settings...

Comment: You can specify `smtp_port=587` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Do I need to specify the smpt_port=587 for this to work? Currently this is the error message I am receiving : 2018-10-19 10:13:38,702 ERROR       pool-14-thread-3|            ScanToEmail| Unable to send email: 
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PR0P264CA0045.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Comment: You can try and test whether adding smtp_port works or not, so just try it.

Answer (score 0):

The **Reasons behind you are receiving 'smtp 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful' error** can be as following:

- It can be your Mail server (like Microsoft outlook or Gmail) error, You are probably **not allowed to use your email to send an email via a relay**. The administrator of the server needs to give the rights to do that.
- You might want **white-list your ip address** by the firewall team. They have to allow connection from your machine.
- Incase of **Gmail you have to allow non secure apps** in setting to access gmail, you can do this by going to your gmail settings.
- Sometime it occurs when **host does not authenticate a user upto a limit** using code, that means if you are sending a mail to a bulk of users like (1000 of users) then it can hang server so if you are sending mail to lots of users then try interval between some amount of users to send mail.
- Or Sometime it can be your programming error, may be you are using programming functions like send mail incorrectly or you have **not configured essential settings** for mail.

Comment: Found the issue. I used a 3rd party SMTP tool to test and found that if SSL is not enabled, SMTP would fail. So now the question is, how do I code in to use SSL onto this .ini file? ; SMTP settings
smtpServer=smtp.office365.com
smtpServerBackup=
emailSender=test@test.co.za
smtpUser=test@test.co.za
smtpPassword=testmypassword

Comment: @ColonelHawx In you php.ini you can set `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` for enabling SSL.

Comment: @ColonelHawx if you are using java, then To enable SMTP connections over SSL, set the
"mail.smtp.ssl.enable" property to "true".